# preg_match multiple expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

hi guys i was wondering how could i build e regExp that says:

"this string may contain 1-25 letters that are not these specific words:"root","bin","download","shutdown"

So I thought:

```
$dang_words="/(root)|(bin)|(shutdown)|(download)/";
$reg_exp="/^[a-z]{1,25}$/";

if(preg_match($reg_exp,$field) || !preg_match($dang_words,$field))
{
 echo "your input it's okkk!";
}
else 
 echo "this is a bad word!!";
```

But it's not working

why?

thanks

Luca

Comment: Do you mean that the string must not *be* one of the bad words or must not *contain* one of the bad words? So, would `rubinia` be allowed or not?

Comment: Just change || to && in your if.

Comment: i just want to allow alphabet letters but dont wont any dangerous word!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$dangerous_words="/(root)|(bin)|(shutdown)|(download)/";
$reg_exp="/^[a-z]{1,25}$/";

if(preg_match($reg_exp,strtolower(trim($field))) && !preg_match($dangerous_words,strtolower(trim($field))))
{
 echo "your input it's okkk!";
}
else 
 echo "this is a bad word!!";
```

You have your logical operators messed up.. Just changed from || to &&.

Answer (score 4):

Close...  Try this:

```
/^(?!.*(root|bin|shutdown|download))[a-z]{1,25}$/
```

It uses a [forward assertion](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

So, it becomes:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?!.*(root|bin|shutdown|download))[a-z]{1,25}$/', $content)) {
    echo "Your input is ok";
} else {
    echo "there is a bad word/invalid content";
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the `-1`?  It works in one regex instead of two...?

Comment: I guess it depends on the interpretation of his intent. Your single regex is different than the combination of his 2 regexes. Yours only flags the string as bad if the string is an exact match for one of the bad words. His method flags the string as bad if the string contains one of the bad words anywhere in the string.

Comment: @brett: thanks, I didn't realize that.  But knowing that now, I can fix that problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies with all the ( ).  In some old code I created a while ago I used this:

```
$stopInjectionVerbs = "/(alter|begin|cast|convert|create|cursor|declare|delete|drop|end|exec|fetch|insert|kill|open|select|sys|table|update)/";
$errors = array();

if (preg_match($stopInjectionVerbs, $select)) {
    $errors[] = "Can not use SQL injection Strings";
}
```

This all works correctly.  Have a go without the brackets around each individual word.

Comment: I just tested against('root') without all those brackets.. and it still says "your input it's ok!!!"